# How do I change these "if"s into a selector string

Tags: coffeescript

I have these if statements, and I am sure it can be shortened. I am very new to coffeescript (and to javascript as well).

```
$ ->
  url = window.location.href.toString()
  urlpart = url.split("//")
  urlpart = urlpart[1].split("#")
  $("#mainTabs a[href=\"#payments\"]").tab "show"  if urlpart[1] is "payments"
  $("#mainTabs a[href=\"#invitations\"]").tab "show"  if urlpart[1] is "invitations"
  $("#mainTabs a[href=\"#orders\"]").tab "show"  if urlpart[1] is "orders"
  $("#mainTabs a[href=\"#campaigns\"]").tab "show"  if urlpart[1] is "campaigns"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use string interpolation to build the jQuery selector, something like:

```
url = window.location.href.toString()
urlpart = url.split("//")
urlpart = urlpart[1].split("#")
$("#mainTabs a[href='##{urlpart[1]}']").tab "show"
```

The `#{...}` bit inside a double quoted string is interpolation. I also switched to single quotes inside the selector to cut down on the backslash noise.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now that I see it, thank you!